# Is there another way to write this in sass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, compass

```
$styles: background #333, margin 20px, padding 10px

.factory
  @each $style in $styles
 #{nth($style, 1)}: nth($style, 2)
```

Is there another way to write this in sass that would mean the same thing? And can anyone explain what this code is doing exactly? It outputs to the following css:

```
.factory {
  background: #333333;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I don't understand what this code is doing.

Comment: What does this have to do with compass?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it line by line:

```
$styles: background #333, margin 20px, padding 10px
```

This declares the global variable `$styles` and assigns it a list of attribute-value pairs.

```
.factory
```

This builds a new class selector `.factory`.

```
  @each $style in $styles
```

This is a loop in Sass, traversing the `$styles` list and one by one assigning each list entry to the variable `$style`, so in the first iteration it will have the value `background #333`, in the next iteration `margin 20px`, and so on.

```
    #{nth($style, 1)}: nth($style, 2)
```

This line uses string interpolation `#{...}` and the `nth` function of Sass lists to build a CSS attribute and its associated value. `background #333` is a list itself in Sass (although only space-separated) and `nth($style, 1)` gives you `background`, while `nth($style, 2)` gives you `#333` in the first iteration of the `@each` loop.

That gives you the already anticipated output. Why are you looking for a different way to achieve this?

Comment: While your answer is acceptable, this type of question is below the standards we like to have here on SO.  It is unclear here what part of the code the OP doesn't understand or why they want to rewrite it to be different, and this kind of question is unlikely to help future users.

Comment: It would be useful to give your opinion on why someone would do these things this way, instead of just writing the CSS out in normal fashion.